# touch screen touch not working properly even after calibration using ts_calibrate

Tags: touch

We are using touchscreen with touch driver (ft5x06). Now to calibrate and test the touch device  i downloaded tslib from github and installed to separate folder by following commands:

```
cd ~/tslib
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/home/user2/Desktop/tslib_arm 
make 
sudo make install
```

now on my embedded board's Desktop has got a folder tslib_arm which consists of compiled code for tslib (like bin, etc,lib etc..)

when i run ts_calibrate(./ts_calibrate) from /home/user2/Desktop/tslib_arm/bin then the calibration screen is coming and calibrating. and if i run  ./ts_test , it gives options like drag and draw, which are also working fine.

But after closing these apps (ts_calibrate or ts_test) and if we check the touch on the Desktop or any application or normal operation touch seems to be uncalibrated only.

Why is it so???

Do i need to copy this tslib_arm or any other files from tslib_arm folder to system's rootfs location????

Answer (score 0):

That's because your "Desktop or any application" most probably doesn't directly implement and use the API that tslib offers (to read touch input samples).

tslib includes [documentation](https://github.com/kergoth/tslib/blob/master/README.md#use-the-filtered-result-in-your-system-xorg-method) on how to use the filtered input in your environment.

What should always work, is using the "**ts_uinput**" daemon program that comes with tslib (just like "ts_calibrate" does). It's a driver for tslib that creates a (second) touchscreen input event device for you in `/dev/input/`. All you need to do is tell your "Desktop or application" to use it. All desktop environments have options to choose which input device you want to use.

Comment: but if i try to run ts_uinput it is giving error "frame buffer device not specified". I run sudo TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0 TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/event0 TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/local/lib/ts ts_uinput -v -d, then also it throws error no /dev/input/uinput device. Even if i run tslib/tools/ts_uinput_start.sh is also failing.

Comment: If you get an error opening "/dev/uinput", the problem is your Linux configuration. You may try to use the (very new) ts_uinput option --nofb that will be in tslib 1.15, if you have problems with your framebuffer device.